# Struts2 handle session timeout using Interceptor

Tags: session, struts2, httprequest, session-timeout, interceptor

I am trying to handle session timeout requests in my struts2 application using an Interceptor. Below are the files related to this:

**Web.xml:**

```
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>1</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

**Struts.xml:**

```
<package name="default" extends="struts-default">
<interceptors>
    <interceptor name="sessionInterceptor"
        class="com.platform.web.security.SessionInterceptor" />
</interceptors>
<action name="doLogin"
    class="com.platform.web.action.LoginAction">
    <result name="input">/login/login.jsp</result>
    <result name="error">/login/login.jsp</result>
    <result type="chain">menuAction</result>
</action>

<action name="menuAction"
    class="com.platform.web.action.MenuAction">
    <interceptor-ref name="sessionInterceptor"/> //Interceptor included here
    <result name="SUCCESS">/jsp/main.jsp</result>
    <result name="ERROR">/login/login.jsp</result>
    <result name="input">/jsp/myFavourite.jsp</result>
</action>
```

**Interceptor Class:**

```
public class SessionInterceptor extends AbstractInterceptor implements StrutsStatics {
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Override
public String intercept(ActionInvocation invocation) throws Exception {

final ActionContext context = invocation.getInvocationContext();
HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) context
    .get(HTTP_REQUEST);
HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);

// Is there a "user" object stored in the user's HttpSession?
//Object user = session.getAttribute("User");
if (session == null) {
    // The user has not logged in yet.

    // Is the user attempting to log in right now?
    //String loginAttempt = request.getParameter(LOGIN_ATTEMPT);

    /* The user is attempting to log in. */
    /*if (!StringUtils.isBlank(loginAttempt)) {
    return invocation.invoke();
    }*/
    return "timeout";
 } else {
    return invocation.invoke();
 }
 }
}
```

**LoginAction:**

```
public class LoginAction extends MesActionSupport implements ServletRequestAware {
@Override
public String execute() throws Exception {
setActionNameForAudit("execute123");
FILE_LOGGER.debug("Entering into execute() ... ");
String strSessionId = "";

if (isValidUser == true) {
    user = getUser();

    strSessionId = request.getSession(true).getId();
    setServletRequest(request);
    session.put("SessionId", strSessionId);

    setSession(session, user);

    ServletActionContext.getRequest().getSession().setAttribute("User", user);

    FILE_LOGGER.debug("Exit from  LoginAction.execute() ... ");
    return SUCCESS;
} else {
    return ERROR;
}
 }
```

**MenuAction:**

```
public class MenuAction extends MesActionSupport implements SessionAware, ParameterAware, RequestAware {
@Override
public String execute() throws Exception {
setActionNameForAudit("execute ");
User user = null; // To store current user
Map<String, ArrayList<String>> category = null; // To store all Menu
// Categories.
StringBuffer menu = new StringBuffer(""); // To store Menu String
StringBuffer dashboardMenu = new StringBuffer("");

// user = (User)(request.getSession().getAttribute("User")==null ? null : request.getSession().getAttribute("User")); //Request object IS NULL HERE!!
user = (User) (mapSession.get("User") == null ? null : mapSession
    .get("User")); // mapSession object IS NULL HERE
FILE_LOGGER.debug("user is " + user == null);

if (user != null) {
    menu = menuView.getMenu(user);
    mapSession.put("Menu", menu.toString());
    mapSession.put("dbMenu", dashboardMenu.toString());
    ret = "SUCCESS";
} else if (user == null) {
    ret = ERROR;
} else {
    ret = SUCCESS;
}
return ret;
}
```

Flow is like this:
1. Login screen opens
2. User enters credentials and submits
3. LoginAction is called, user is authenticated
4. If valid user - MenuAction is called. Else redirect to Login.jsp

According to the above code, the session gets created in the LoginAction, control reaches the Interceptor where the session object is checked. If session exists the control reaches MenuAction.

But when this happens, the `request` object gets reset to NULL! Earlier when I was not using an interceptor, the flow was working completely fine between LoginAction and MenuAction.

Does the interceptor resets the HTTPRequest? and hence the Session? As a result I am not able to proceed.

Any help?

Answer (score 16):

I have many comments on this code/configuration, some trivial, some not.

1. There's zero reason to create your own session; don't.
2. When you declare an interceptor in an action configuration you must declare *all* interceptors. As configured, *only* the session interceptor is running for `menuAction`.
3. That means no parameters will be filled, since no other interceptors are running.
4. In general, only use `SessionAware` to access the session. There is *very* rarely a need to access the request directly.
5. Obviously the interceptor doesn't "set the request to null", that doesn't even make sense.
6. I have no idea what your `LoginAction` is supposed to be doing. What's the *intent* of lines like `setServletRequest(request);` or `setSession(session, user);`? There's nothing about those two lines that look correct.
7. Name your success and error results just that, `"success"` and `"error"` (lower case), if you're going to use the `ActionSupport.SUCCESS` and `ActionSupport.ERROR` constants. If you're *not* using those constants in this code, I'd recommend using other names for them, because it will confuse anybody that has actually used Struts 2 before.
8. When posting code samples please remove stuff that isn't relevant. Particularly when you don't explicitly set syntax highlighting it makes things *much* more difficult to read.
9. Don't use code like `if (isValidUser == true)`, use `if (isValidUser)`.
10. Mind your conditionals: stuff like `if (user == null) ... else if (user != null) ... else ...` makes zero sense. The user is null, or it isn't: there's no third option.
11. Avoid unnecessary, confusing logic, like `User currentUser = (User) (mapSession.get("User") == null ? null : mapSession.get("User"));` which basically says "If it's null, use null, otherwise return the value you just got, but get it again." WHY???
12. Comments like `User user = null; // To store current user` are completely worthless. Isn't it *obvious* what `User user` is? A user. Not obvious enough? How about `User currentUser`???
13. Name plurals (e.g., collections) as something plural. A map of category names to lists isn't a single category.
14. Don't declare variables far away from where they're used; it's very confusing.
15. Put your JSP pages under `WEB-INF` somewhere to disallow direct client access.
16. Avoid unnecessary language constructs, like when an `if` branch returns, an `else` isn't strictly necessary, and IMO, it adds noise. Similarly, consider returning as soon as you know you're returning. The latter is a bit more controversial, but I think people are coming around to realizing it's okay to have multiple return points in short methods, and IMO it's easier to think about.
17. Use less code to say things. Create little utility methods to wrap up trivial functionality so it doesn't pollute the mainline code.
18. Use action chaining almost never.

There's more, but that's enough for now. Here's the actual relevant code, cleaned up. Some of it isn't actually relevant but I left it in anyway.

---

```xml
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<session-config>
  <session-timeout>1</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

```xml
<package name="default" extends="struts-default">
  <interceptors>
    <interceptor name="sessionInterceptor" class="com.platform.web.security.SessionInterceptor" />
  </interceptors>

  <action name="doLogin" class="com.platform.web.action.LoginAction">
    <result name="input">/WEB-INF/jsp/login/login.jsp</result>
    <result name="error">/WEB-INF/jsp/login/login.jsp</result>
    <result type="redirectAction">menuAction</result>
  </action>

  <action name="menuAction" class="com.platform.web.action.MenuAction">
    <interceptor-ref name="sessionInterceptor"/>
    <result name="success">/WEB-INF/jsp/main.jsp</result>
    <result name="input">/WEB-INF/jsp/myFavourite.jsp</result>
  </action>
```

```java
 public class SessionInterceptor extends AbstractInterceptor implements StrutsStatics {
    @Override
    public String intercept(ActionInvocation invocation) throws Exception {
        ActionContext context = invocation.getInvocationContext();
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) context.get(HTTP_REQUEST);
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);

        // session will almost *never* be null. Check for a valid user object.
        if (session == null) {
            return "timeout";
        }

        return invocation.invoke();
    }
}
```

```java
public class LoginAction extends MesActionSupport implements ServletRequestAware {
    @Override
    public String execute() throws Exception {
        if (!isValidUser) {
            return ERROR;
        }

        user = getUser();

        String strSessionId = request.getSession(true).getId();
        setServletRequest(request);
        session.put("SessionId", strSessionId);

        setSession(session, user);

        ServletActionContext.getRequest().getSession().setAttribute("User", user);

        return SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

```java
public class MenuAction extends MesActionSupport implements SessionAware, ParameterAware, RequestAware {
    @Override
    public String execute() throws Exception {
        User currentUser = (User) mapSession.get("User");
        if (currentUser == null) {
            return ERROR;
        }

        Map<String, List<String>> categories; // Left in for naming.

        StringBuffer menu = menuView.getMenu(user);
        mapSession.put("Menu", menu.toString());

        StringBuffer dashboardMenu = new StringBuffer("");
        mapSession.put("dbMenu", dashboardMenu.toString());

        return SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 I would give it another upvote if I could because it was also funny. Goes to show a lot of motivation can come out of an annoyed programmer! Join the dark side.

Answer (score 2):

There's *no way* you can tell between whether the session has timed out or it just hasn't been created yet in your interceptor, unless you add some tracking to your front-end, in primitive case it could be just a single request parameter.

A combination of [HttpSessionListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionListener.html) and [Servlet3 + AJAX Push notifications](http://java.dzone.com/articles/non-blocking-nio-server-push) would be the *right* way to do it.

Comment: It doesn't matter if it hasn't been created or it timed out; either way the user isn't valid. I don't understand over-complicating something that's relatively simple.

Comment: he says he wants to _handle session timeout requests_ - that is supposed to be different from checking if user is valid or not, but who knows

Comment: I sure don't--I thought the OP meant "I made a request but my session has timed out" based on the code, but it was also difficult for m to understand the code :/ +1 anyway :)